# Replace prompt and prevent selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help in my code here please.
i write a function that select item from selector and on the change of  it a function will run.
I face 2 problems here ,firstly i want to change prompt with other widget in Js or Jquery without using any HTML,because prompt is so silly and if the user prevent alerts this will be a big problem.
The second problem that i have a condition that if the string coming from prompt is not what i  want then it shouldn't select the other item and stay on the first 1.
Here is my JS code :

```
self.$('#cashier-select')
                .change(function () {
                    new instance.web.Model("res.users").call('get_pincode', [this.value]).done(
                        function (results) {
                            var person = prompt("Please enter your pin code", "");
                            if (person == results) {
                                var id = this.value;
                                self.cashier_change(id);
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("In Vaild noob");
                                self.cashier_change(globalCashier);
                            }
                            console.log("person " + results);
                        });
                });

cashier_change: function (id) {
            globalCashier = id;
            new instance.web.Model("res.users").call('get_pincode', [id]).done(
                function (results) {

                    console.log(results);
                });
            var name = $('select#cashier-select>option[value="' + globalCashier + '"]').text();
            $('#pay-screen-cashier-name').html(name);
            $('.username').text(name);
            if (name != '') {
                $('.gotopay-button').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('.gotopay-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        },
```

**Note i create the selector using Jquery i didn't use any HTML :)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a good variety of jquery plugins. Most of the [alert plugins found here](https://plugins.jquery.com/?s=alert) can also be used as a `prompt`.

You can use [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), one of the many alert/prompt plugins, to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
$("button").on("click", prompt);

function prompt() {
  //Example taken directly from the SweetAlert main page
  swal({
    title: "An input!",
    text: "Write something interesting:",
    type: "input",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
    inputPlaceholder: "Write something",
    inputType: "password"
  }, function(inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === false) return false;
    if (inputValue === "") {
      swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
      return false
    }
    swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Prompt Me!</button>
```

Comment: great i liked it but what if i want the input is to be password ,, i mean hidden ?

Comment: If you inspect the API in their site, you will see there is a `inputType` parameter. You can use that. Updated the answer also.

Comment: Great i looked at it .. and it's cool, i would like to mark it as solved but it is not ,, i still face my 2nd problem :( when the validation fails the select box is still selecting :(

Comment: Do not immediately display a success swal when confirm button is clicked. Look at the example, for example it validates that user has written something. If They did not right anything, it shows an input error. You could validate the user entered values in a similar manner.

Comment: i tried that ... but it's useless since if click to change the select box and the prompt came out and if he cancel this prompt  the select will be done also ! :(